# Celery not work: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//

Tags: python, django, celery

I can not run the celery worker + docker + django. I download image rabbit and linked worker, and at run I get error: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 111] Connection refused.
worker_1. Django: 1.11, calary: 4.1.0. What doing wrong?

docker-compose

```
rabbit:
  image: rabbitmq:latest
  ports:
    - "5672:5672"

worker:
  build: ./project
  volumes:
    - ./main:/src/app
  depends_on:
    - rabbit
  links:
    - web #django project
  entrypoint: /src/app/calery.sh
```

calery

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'app.settings')

app = Celery('app')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='APP')

app.autodiscover_tasks()

@app.task(bind=True)
def add():
   print('Task')
```

celery.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

cd app
celery -A app worker -l info
```

Comment: do u have `Celery` instance started? something like `celery -A my_project worker -l info`?

Comment: Yes, all right, this command writed in calery.sh

Comment: Can you show the content of calery.sh? and the value of `CELERY_BROKER_URL`?

Comment: I added celery.sh higher and  CELERY_BROKER_URL is not defined. I not see this point in: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#using-celery-with-django

Comment: @SergBombermen That is because there is a default value for it and you are using it, you can check their [sample project](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/master/examples/django/proj/settings.py#L9) for configurations.

Answer (score 6):

The error is caused by invalid host for `CELERY_BROKER_URL`.  Based on the error you provided, it seems that the host in your broker url is `127.0.0.1`, since you are using docker, this will not work unless you provide the public IP of your host. You need to update the host in your `CELERY_BROKER_URL` to use the service name in you compose file.  In your case it is `rabbit`.  Something like below should work:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://guest:guest@rabbit:5672/%2F'
```

Change the user and password and other details.

Comment: @SergBombermen Can you change it to include the username and password? something like `amqp://guest:guest@rabbit:5672/%2F` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't access with the guest:guest, add your own user to the system. This doc can help you setup your own user, password and Virtual Host inside your RabbitMQ server.

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/rabbitmq.html#broker-rabbitmq